# Python lists from csv file

Tags: python, list

I am working on an assignment for plotting graphs from a csv file with movies and they have different categories to them like genres, budget, director's name, etc. We are asked to put the genres (key) and movies (values) in a dictionary and then put the other categories into a list or a tuple to match the movies. I have already created the dictionary, by genres that match movies. How would I go about creating lists of the other categories and match them to the movies to graph?
This is what I have so far:

```
def find_col_ind(columns):
   ind = -1
   ind_col_genres = -1
   ind_col_movie = -1

   for col in columns:
       ind += 1

       if col == 'movie_title':
          ind_col_movie = ind
       elif col == 'genres':
          ind_col_genres = ind

   return ind_col_genres, ind_col_movie


def create_dict(filename):
   with open('C:\\Users\\jayan\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\IMDB_movie_metadata_for_assignment_6.csv', 'r',errors='ignore') as csvfile:

    data = dict()
    is_first = True

    for line in csvfile:
        columns = line.split(',')
        if is_first:
            ind_col_genres, ind_col_movie = find_col_ind(columns)
            is_first = False
            continue

        genres = columns[ind_col_genres].split('|')
        movie = columns[ind_col_movie]

        for genre in genres:
            if genre in data:
                data[genre].append(movie.strip('\nÂ\xa0 '))
            else:
                data[genre] = [movie.strip('\nÂ\xa0 ')]


    return data





if __name__ == "__main__":
data = create_dict("C:\\Users\\jayan\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\IMDB_movie_metadata_for_assignment_6.csv")
print(data)
```

Comment: i suggest you use the [`csv` moudle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) could simplify your code a lot!

Comment: It's worth noting that the code you presented above will never run because of your lack of indentation before the last two lines.